# ruby configatron foreach, How to display the name of a config?

Tags: ruby, configatron

I want to see `test` and `test2`

```
configatron.providers.test.remote_dir = '/incoming/test/current'
configatron.providers.test.local_dir = 'data/test'
configatron.providers.test2.remote_dir = '/incoming/test2/current'
configatron.providers.test2.local_dir = 'data/test2'


configatron.providers.foreach do |p| 
    p.name() #<--- how to display test/test2
end
```

Tried reading the manual? did I miss this somewhere? Google was no help.

Thanks.

Comment: ```p.local_dir``` does not work?! or what exactly is your problem?

Comment: well that sort of doesn't work either. when I put puts p.local_dir, it returns a Configatron::Store<id> object.

Answer (score 0):

i guess this is what you are looking for:

```
configatron.providers.configatron_keys.map { |key| configatron.providers.send(key).local_dir }
```

Comment: kind of. If I'm looping on providers (to do something with them), why can't I just simply get the name of the current provider i'm on without changing my whole natural foreach loop to what you have above?

Comment: Here's a use case. Logging! What if a I want to log the name of that provider. i.e. loop through the providers log.info("Initializing provider #{x}..."), then do something with provider configs.

Comment: i mean that configatron is not a great fit here. as you can see it is possible to iterate over your providers. so what more do you need?

Comment: The providers are "configurable" (i.e. in a config file changed by admin). They change, hence the foreach loop. It would be nice to print the name of the provider I'm currently processing in a log or to screen. Guess that's too much to ask of configatron.